# Python multiprocess, fast computation of a big matrix

Tags: python, matrix, multiprocessing

everyone, I am trying to make the following computation.

I have an 2D n*d numpy array A, each of its row is a d-dimensional datapoint x. I want to compute a n*n matrix B, each of its element B[i, j ] =  f( A[i], A[j]), where f(p,q) is a symmetric function applies to every possible pair of datap0ints, however, it has some non-linear operation, and it cannot be easily vectorized.

Since n and d can be very large, n~200000, d~1000, this computation is very slow, I am trying to speed it up using multiprocessing.Pool()

This is the code I am having so far, I am intentionally ignore the symmetry property ( B[i,j]==B[j,i]) for simplicity.

```
p = Pool(cpu_count())

for i, x in enumerate(A):
    B[i] = p.map(functools.partial(f , x) , A)
```

I am fixing one parameter of f() as one element of A, and apply map() = to the iterable  nparray A, so that I can get the answer for one row at a time.

The problem with this is the speed, it is even slower than my original elementwise computation when I tried it with (n,d) = (1000, 100).

After reading many other related posts, I guess this is because the function f() has been pickled and unpickled back and forth, inducing huge overhead.

Do I guess it right? Is there a better way of doing this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to be using vectorized operations. NumPy's performance benefits only happen when you put all the heavy computational work onto NumPy's efficient vectorized builtins. What's `f`, and how are you computing it in the single-process case?

Comment: @user2357112, thanks a lot for your quick reply. f() function has some non-linear operation inside, and hardly can be vectorized, more specifically, it computes the DTW(dynamic time warping) between to signals/datapoints.